# How to show preview passage in PDF viewer page by page

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf, preview

[image: I have an Preview of content like passage around 2000 lines]

Is it possible to show that in PDF viewer like page by page instead of having from top to bottom which was around 2000 lines.

Comment: Have you looked at the [PDF viewer documentation](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf)? Right near the start, the basic usage example shows rendering of a single page using the `<Page/>` component, and stores the current page number in state.

Comment: I need to show it from html